# sort list of dictionaries based on keys inside the list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort this based on the `key` in `dictionary`?

```
df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1}), ('f', {'mos': 1}), ('f', {'esc': 1})]
```

I tried this

```
L1 = [year for (title, year) in (sorted(df1.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))]
```

I want

```
df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'esc': 1}), ('f', {'mos': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1})]
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the use of storing one-item dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a separate function to get the only item in an iterable:

```
def only(iterable):
    x, = iterable
    return x
```

Dicts are iterables of keys:

```
>>> only({'abe': 1})
'abe'

>>> only({'tbeli': 1})
'tbeli'
```

so you can use it for your sort:

```
sorted(df1, key=lambda t: only(t[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the dicts are going to be only 1 key/pair long then this should work.

`L1=sorted(df1, key=lambda t: list(t[1].keys())[0])`